# C++ Using upper_bound instead of find ()

Tags: c++, vector, find

I need advice on how to modify the program so that I can search using the upper/lower_bound function. The program works correctly(ok asserts) for the find () function.
I sort the company database after each insertion or deletion, so that's probably not the problem
In the link I enclose the whole program for a better understanding.
https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3xxyvx8vw

```
bool Company::operator == (Company cmpx)  const
{ 

    return ( ( (strcasecmp(addr.c_str(), cmpx.addr.c_str()) == 0) 
            && (strcasecmp(name.c_str(), cmpx.name.c_str()) == 0) )
            || (id == cmpx.id)
    );
    
}

bool Company::operator < (Company cmpx) const
{

    return id < cmpx.id;
}
bool CVATRegister::cancelCompany ( const string &taxID )
{
    Company cmp("", "", taxID);

    //auto itr = upper_bound(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), cmp); THIS NOT WORK
    auto itr = find(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), cmp);  

    if(itr != DCompany.end())
     {   
        DCompany.erase(itr);
        sort(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), [](const Company & a, const Company & b)
        { 
            return a.getId() < b.getId(); 
        });
        return true;
     }
     
     return false;
}
```

Comment: [upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) returns an iterator to the first element _greater than_ `cmp`. Since `cmp` is not greater than itself, the iterator you get is pointing to one past `cmp` (if `cmp` is present in `DCompany`, of course.)

Comment: It's not clear to me why you'd want to use `upper_bound` here at all. If your intention is to get faster searches by relying on the fact that you keep `DCompany` sorted, perhaps [std::binary_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Best way to think of upper and lower bound is that they give you insertion indexes

Comment: There's nothing in the shown code that documents how the vector is sorted, a prerequisite for using `upper_bound`. If it was sorted, then the shown logic makes no sense, because after `erase()` it from the vector there would be no reason, whatsoever, to sort it again, because the remaining vector will still be sorted. Your question is unclear.

Comment: You should also be aware, you probably want to do a remove before you call erase.

Comment: @NathanPierson but with std :: binary_search I can't access the index / iterator?

Comment: Oops, that's a good point. So maybe something with `upper_bound` but backtracking one element, checking equality, etc. Probably worth writing a little wrapper function that handles that and returns the past-the-end iterator if the value isn't found, for instance.

Comment: You also don't need to resort your sequence apocalypse, assuming ordering is following the rules. If you have `a < b < c`, and you locate `b` for deletion, the remainder, `a < c`,  is still sorted.

Comment: @NathanPierson I think `std::binary_search` is the most poorly named function in `std`.  You generally want to use `std::lower_bound` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `DCompany` is sorted with respect to `Company::operator<` (i.e. with respect to the company tax ID), then you can do:

```cpp
bool CVATRegister::cancelCompany ( const string &taxID )
{
    Company const cmp("", "", taxID);
    
    auto const itr = lower_bound(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), cmp);
    if(itr != DCompany.end() && itr->getId() == taxId)
    {   
        DCompany.erase(itr);

        // 1. No need to pass a lamda to sort your container again,
        //    since your Company::operator< will be called.
        // 2. No need to sort again your container after removing an
        //    element: it will already be sorted.
        //sort(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), [](const Company & a, const Company & b)
        //{ 
        //    return a.getId() < b.getId(); 
        //});

        return true;
     }
     
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lower_bound` to find and then compare with `taxID`

#### Like this:

```
bool CVATRegister::cancelCompany(const string &taxID)
{
    Company cmp("", "", taxID);

    auto itr = lower_bound(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), cmp); 
    //auto itr = find(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), cmp);

    if (itr != DCompany.end() && itr->getId() == taxID) {
        DCompany.erase(itr);
        sort(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), [](const Company & a, const Company & b) {
            return a.getId() < b.getId();
        });
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```